# How to filter WebRTC codecs in the native iOS app

Tags: ios, webrtc, codec, webrtc-ios

Is there any way to set audio/video codec preferences for `RTP` sender in iOS WebRTC lib before `SDP` creation?

`RTCRtpSender -> parameters -> codecs` array is empty until the peer connection ice gathering state is `complete`, but this state is only reported via callback after the `SDP` creation.

Using M91 WebRTC.

Answer (score 1):

In theory the transceiver.setCodecPreferences API can do that.
It does not seem to be implemented in the iOS SDK though.

Comment: I've tried different approaches with setting codecs, but no effect.